# How to perform mode function on multiple columns in Google Big Query

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

Let`s assume table with a large number of columns in GBQ, eg.:

```
+----+----+----+----+-----+------+
| ID | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | ... | Q500 |
+----+----+----+----+-----+------+
|  1 |  1 | 0  |  1 | ... |   2  |
|  2 |  0 | 1  |  0 | ... |   3  |
|... | ...| ...| ...| ... |  ... |
| 99 |  3 |  2 |  1 | ... |   0  |
+----+----+----+----+-----+------+
```

I would like to perform a query with MODE and COUNT function on every column to get the most frequent value and its count per column, something like:

```
         +----+----+----+-----+------+
(column) | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | ... | Q500 | 
(mode)   | 0  | 1  | 3  | ... |  2   |
(count)  | 10 | 56 | 23 | ... |  50  |
         +----+----+----+-----+------+
```

I can use mode to calculate this but I need to use every column name explicitly. Is there a workaround to get these results without specifying every column name?

Comment: I don't think there is.  Your code would be much simpler if you had one row per id and "Q" value.

Comment: I agree, but I cannot change the table schema at the moment. Right now I just put whole rows straight from GBQ to DataFrame and counting it there but it is slow and inefficient. Getting such data straight from the table would be a significant game-changer.

Comment: I can see how to got columns --> JSON --> Array but not back to individual columns.

Comment: I think your best bet will be a Pandas dataframe in Python (you have this question tagged with `python`, hence my suggestion).  Also, depending on if this is something you will need repeatedly or just as a one-off, Excel or Google Sheets would make this pretty easy as well.

Comment: I used pandas for this task, but because a huge number of columns and rows in the table this was totally slow (also considering sending the table from GBQ to Pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and is inline with Gordon's comments

```
#standardSQL
SELECT column,
  SUM(value) total_value,
  AVG(value) avg_value
FROM (
  SELECT 
    SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)] column,
    CAST(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) value
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
  UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'[{}"]', ''))) kv
)
WHERE column != 'id'
GROUP BY column
```

it produces something like below

```
Row     column  total_value avg_value    
1       q1      4           1.3333333333333333   
2       q2      3           1.0  
3       q3      2           0.6666666666666666   
...     ...     ...         ...
500     q500    5           1.6666666666666667
```

I second Gordon and really think that this output is more practical in most use cases

But if for some reason you still want to pivot result - there are plenty Posts here on SO for BigQuery on how to do so

Also note:

- above solution assumes your values are of INT64 type but you can use FLOAT64 or NUMERIC if thsis is the data type you have
- in example I use SUM and AVG, but you can use whatever aggregation functions you need

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!